# How to open url with ACTION_VIEW intent from onStartJob of JobScheduler

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-jobscheduler

I am trying to open a url in the browser using `ACTION_VIEW` intent from the `onStartJob` method of `JobScheduler` `Service`. Below is the code:

MainActivity

```java
package com.rohitkhatri.jobscheduler;

import android.app.job.JobInfo;
import android.app.job.JobScheduler;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.rohitkhatri.jobscheduler.MyService;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final int JOB_ID = 101;
    JobScheduler jobScheduler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

        scheduleJob();
    }

    public void scheduleJob() {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, MyService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, componentName);
        jobInfo.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY);

        int response = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo.build());

        if (response == JobScheduler.RESULT_FAILURE) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

MyService

```java
package com.rohitkhatri.jobscheduler;

import android.app.job.JobService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends JobService {
    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Job executed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://google.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Job Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rohitkhatri.jobscheduler">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
09-30 20:57:31.486 30106-30106/com.rohitkhatri.jobscheduler E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rohitkhatri.jobscheduler, PID: 30106
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
  at android.app.job.JobService$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobService.java:130)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:672)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:659)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:331)
  at com.rohitkhatri.jobscheduler.MyService.onStartJob(MyService.java:23)
  at android.app.job.JobService$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobService.java:126)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Comment: "I am trying to open a url in the browser using ACTION_VIEW intent from the onStartJob method of JobScheduler Service" -- why on Earth would the user want this? You have no specific control over when the job is invoked, and the user may be in the middle of doing something important. If you want to advise the user of an event from the background, use a `Notification`, please.

Comment: I know, but It's only for my own purpose. I won't be distributing this app, only will be installing in my phone to fulfil my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to set FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag in order to call startActivity() from outside of an activity context

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://google.com"));
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, it's *terrible* UX to launch UI out of nowhere, interrupting whatever the user is doing and probably causing them to false-touch on things.  You should post a suitable notification instead.